# I am trying to change the layout data from this to that layout

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, layout, formatting

I am trying to change the data layout from this layout in pandas:

| Material | Category | 001.2023 | 002.2023 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 6001 | Price | 16 | 47 |
| 6002 | Price | 50 | 41 |
| 6003 | Price | 3 | 5 |
| 6001 | Discounts | 35 | 47 |
| 6002 | Discounts | 41 | 33 |
| 6003 | Discounts | 7 | 27 |
| 6001 | Quantity | 34 | 41 |
| 6002 | Quantity | 5 | 15 |
| 6003 | Quantity | 7 | 50 |

to this layout:

| Material | Date | Price | Discounts | Quantity |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 6001 | 001.2023 | 16 | 35 | 34 |
| 6002 | 001.2023 | 50 | 41 | 5 |
| 6003 | 001.2023 | 3 | 7 | 7 |
| 6001 | 002.2023 | 47 | 47 | 41 |
| 6002 | 002.2023 | 41 | 33 | 15 |
| 6003 | 002.2023 | 5 | 27 | 50 |

I tried to use the function `stack` and `wide`*`to`*`long`  but neither of them work properly.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this:

```
result = (df.set_index(['Material', 'Category'])
          .rename_axis(columns='Date')
          .stack()
          .unstack(level=1)
          .reset_index()
          .sort_values(['Date', 'Material'])
          .rename_axis(columns=None)
          )
print(result)

>>>
   Material      Date  Discounts  Price  Quantity
0      6001  001.2023         35     16        34
2      6002  001.2023         41     50         5
4      6003  001.2023          7      3         7
1      6001  002.2023         47     47        41
3      6002  002.2023         33     41        15
5      6003  002.2023         27      5        50
```